# ASP.NET grid view does not retain spaces

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, gridview, datagridview

ASP.NET grid view does not retain spaces and next line created by Enter keys, when loaded from database.

I have a multiline textbox, when I save and load the same text in Grid, the grid removes all spaces and enter key's next line. it loads up all together like the example below.

Multiline text box :

This is a default property that when one presses 
Enter key in the textbox the form gets submitted in other words 
there is a postback.

So many people asked on forums. 
1. How to disable enter key in textbox?

Grid view pulls up like this:

This is a default property that when one presses Enter key in the textbox the form gets submitted in other words there is a postback. So many people asked on forums. 1. How to disable enter key in textbox?

Please suggest how to retain spaces.
Thank you.

Comment: Remember, a space has no meaning in HTML. HTML itself ignores any spaces after the first space. A line break has no meaning in HTML and will only render as a linebreak in the source. If you want multiple spaces, you would have to translate them to a non-breaking space &nbsp;  For line breaks, replace them with <br />.

Comment: first make sure its gridview or datagridview.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends how line breaks etc are actually stored. In my case I can use `.Replace()` inside the gridview on `Eval`.:

```
<asp:Label ID="lblOptionNotes" runat="server"
    Text='<%# Eval("OptionNotes").ToString().Replace("\r\n", "<br />") %>'>
</asp:Label>
```

which replaces carriage returns and new lines with html line breaks.